# How to Get Custom Attribute Back?

Tags: c#, reflection

Say I have this property with this attribute

```
[StringLength(3)]
public string Owner { get; set; }
```

How can i use reflection to get me back

```
"[StringLength(3)]"
```

I don't care if it is returned as a string or if I have to rebuild it but I want to have that result that I can access.

Comment: You want the string of the value passed in the contructor?

Comment: Or do you actually want the string `[StringLength(3)]`?

Comment: I literally want the a string back with that in it(and any other attributes that maybe on that property). I am going property by property extracting those attributes out.

Comment: You can't literally get the source string unless you have access to the source code.  That is, you have no way from the assembly of knowing whether the source code has `[StringLength(3)]` as opposed to `[StringLengthAttribute(0x3)]` or some other possibility.  Is that a problem for you?

Comment: I have the source code. just playing around with reflection. Won't be a complete solution to handle every case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough code to get you going, assuming your class is called `Test` and the property is called `Owner`:

```
var attributeStrings = typeof(Test)
    .GetProperty("Owner")
    .CustomAttributes   
    .Select(a => 
        string.Format(
            "[{0}({1})]",
            a.AttributeType.Name.Replace("Attribute",""),
            string.Join(", ", a.ConstructorArguments.Select(ca => ca.Value))
));
```

Comment: Among other problems, this would fail with [XmlAtributeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @phoog Indeed, I was tempted to leave the `Replace` out completely, after all - that's the actual class that is in use anyway.

Comment: It depends on whether the actual string is needed, of course, or just a possible string.  The first is impossible without access either to the source code or perhaps, if it exists, to any strict coding style rule in use by the programmer.  But, as you said, your answer is a starting point, not a complete solution.